# STM32 "blue pill" st-flash error

Tags: stm32

I am trying to flash STM32 "blue pill" using arduino IDE as mentioned in the link https://www.onetransistor.eu/2017/11/stm32-bluepill-arduino-ide.html#no-bootloader

Basically using MX linux as OS.

The following is the response

```
user@mx:~/.arduino15/packages/stm32duino/tools/stm32tools/2021.5.31/linux/stlink
$ ./st-flash --reset write ~/Desktop/generic_boot20_pc13.bin 0x8000000
2021-07-27T09:20:21 INFO src/common.c: Loading device parameters....
2021-07-27T09:20:21 INFO src/common.c: Device connected is: F1 Medium-density device, id 0x20036410
2021-07-27T09:20:21 INFO src/common.c: SRAM size: 0x5000 bytes (20 KiB), Flash: 0x20000 bytes (128 KiB) in pages of 1024 bytes
2021-07-27T09:20:21 INFO src/common.c: Attempting to write 22268 (0x56fc) bytes to stm32 address: 134217728 (0x8000000)
Flash page at addr: 0x08005400 erased
2021-07-27T09:20:21 INFO src/common.c: Finished erasing 22 pages of 1024 (0x400) bytes
2021-07-27T09:20:21 INFO src/common.c: Starting Flash write for VL/F0/F3 core id
2021-07-27T09:20:21 ERROR src/common.c: unknown coreid, not sure what flash loader to use, aborting!: 2ba01477
2021-07-27T09:20:21 WARN src/common.c: Failed to write flash loader to sram!
2021-07-27T09:20:21 ERROR src/common.c: init_flash_loader() == -1
stlink_fwrite_flash() == -1
user@mx:~/.arduino15/packages/stm32duino/tools/stm32tools/2021.5.31/linux/stlink
$
```

I am not finding any src/common.c program in any of the subfolders, hence unable to dwell into details of the unknown core ID error

STlink V2 is providing proper response for st-info --probe as below

```
user@mx:~/.arduino15/packages/stm32duino/tools/stm32tools/2021.5.31/linux/stlink
$ ./st-info --probe
Found 1 stlink programmers
 serial: 4a3307000e144c37514d4e00
openocd: "\x4a\x33\x07\x00\x0e\x14\x4c\x37\x51\x4d\x4e\x00"
  flash: 131072 (pagesize: 1024)
   sram: 20480
 chipid: 0x0410
  descr: F1 Medium-density device
user@mx:~/.arduino15/packages/stm32duino/tools/stm32tools/2021.5.31/linux/stlink
```

Please let me know if you can find any method resolve this error

Comment: I recommend you https://www.stm32duino.com

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the website.